# Variable with two user inputs

Tags: python

```
rentalPeriod = input("Number of Weeks Rented:\n")
```

I need some help with using one variable and two user inputs and then to print out the rentalPeriod using the two variables with a logical operator using or. With the second string "Number of Days Rented:\n as the second input

Answer (score 0):

This can be an option:

```
var1, var2 = input("Enter two numbers here: ").split()
```

or you can do the following:

```
var1, var2 = input('Two numbers please (with a comma in between): ').split(',')
```

Comment: Now I did, the 2nd was missing a split. Thanks :)